# Refactoring static class so I can unit test it

Tags: java

I have a static class that I would like to refactor so I can change the name of the properties file etc., and to be able to unit test it easier.

Current I have this:

```
public enum MySettings {

   INSTANCE;

   //priv vars
   private string applicationUrl;

   private MySettings() {

     MappingJsonFactory jf = new MappingJsonFactory();

    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream mySettingsInputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("a.properties");

    Properties mySettingsProperties = new Properties().load(mySettingsInputStream);

    // code below to load json and set priv vars etc.




   }

   public String getApplicationUrl() {
       return applicationUrl;
   }
}
```

How could I set the name of the properties file to something else in my unit tests?

Comment: Pass it in as a constructor arg?

Comment: maybe make it accessible with a setter.
or saving it the a.properties part in a constants class.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth pass an argument to an enum ctor? No...

Comment: @MattBall: Yep, I missed that this was an enum.  But, clearly if the OP wants this to be non-static, he's going to need to use an actual class...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Inversion of control."  The simplest way to do this here would be to take it in as a constructor arg.  At the higher end would be an IOC framework, such as Spring.

Worse case since you're dealing with an `enum` - may need to factor out an interface then provide an implementing enum.  Or better:

```
public enum Settings {
    PRODUCTION("prod.xml"), UNIT_TESTING("dev.xml");
    //...
```

Comment: The idea with a second version in the enum is quite ingenious :P. Simple, yet powerful.

Comment: @MartinBraun: Hmm, maybe.  One of the key tenets of unit testing is not to have special "if_test_mode" hooks in the code to be tested... (which I think is what the second idea is equivalent to)

Comment: thanks, actually I could create a empty constructor and then one with a parameter, and then do chaining so I don't have to modify all other references. thanks.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth with factoring out an interface likely; with separately constructing enums this is pretty healthy since the different is data driven (and OP makes it sound necessary, I mean, unit tests shouldn't hit production DBs for isntance).

Answer (score 0):

you could fiddle all the stuff from the enum class into a real instantiable class (via package protection or protected) and then make an instance of it accessible via the enum (getter). Like this you can unit test everything like a charm and also have it as a singleton :). With this you don't need a second Enum constant (as pointed out in the comments).

If you are using protected instead of package protection you can unit test it by creating a dummy class that inherits from the actual class and instantiate it in the test like this:

```
private static class Dummy extends NewClass {

    public Dummy() {
        super();
    }

}
```